Macbook Pro 2019 Intel Stuck At Apple Logo When Clean Install Bootable USB
Here's what happened:

I updated my Mac OS from Sonoma to the latest version (Sequoia).
After the update restart, I found that my Wi-Fi wasn't working properly. It was connected, but the internet wasn't working. Additionally, when I restarted, it would always get stuck at the Apple logo at 50% loading, then restart in a loop.
I decided to clean install my Mac. I entered safe boot, created a bootable USB using the terminal (100% successful), then went to Disk Utility and erased my HD data.
After that, I tried to boot using the bootable USB. I turned on the laptop and pressed the Option key.
The Internet Recovery screen was displayed, along with the option to install from USB (Sequoia). I selected the install from USB (Sequoia) option, but it started to download something with Internet Recovery. After waiting 10-20 minutes, the screen changed to the Apple logo and started loading.

However, the problem is that it got stuck on the Apple logo at 40-50% loading. I waited for about 20 more minutes, and then my laptop restarted on its own.
I'm not sure what happened, but you should know that I don't have the LCD on my laptop anymore. It broke, so I decided to remove it a couple of months ago. Now, I'm connecting the laptop to an external monitor.
What can I do? Is there any solution for this issue?

Did you erase just the Data volume on the internal disk, or the whole thing? It's likely you need to connect it to another Mac which can reinstall, repair, or 'revive' the Mac. Normally, I'd suggest you take it to an Apple Store or other authorised repair shop. But if there's a history of hardware failure and "surgery"... Also: It's very unlikely that an OS update caused Wifi issues of this sort, so I would have investigated configuration settings and tested in known good networks.

@benwiggy Thanks for your response. Now my Mac is solved with DFU method
